# Any chart library that can fill an area by object value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, charts

I have a simple Area chart powered by recharts (just for example)

```
const data = [
  {
    uv: 200,
    veracity: 'low',
  },
  {
    uv: 300,
    veracity: 'medium',
  }
];

<AreaChart data={data}>
 <Area
  type='monotone'
  dataKey='uv'
  stroke='#8884d8'
  fill='black'
  />
</AreaChart>
```

I want to fill area by `veracity` value in data obj. For example, i want it to work something like this

`fill={props => props.veracity === 'low' ? 'black' : 'white'}`

[recharts documentaion](http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/AreaChartFillByValue) have similar example, but Area color changed by value, not by other keys in data object. I found out few similar questions on github, but no one has answer.

I want to achieve a result like this
[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example in the documentation provided is a clever hack using a CSS linear gradient that effectively acts as a "binary" selector between green or red, based on if the y-axis value is above or below the value `0`. Unfortunately, Recharts does not provide a way to specify a custom fill function that will automagically handle these color changes for the area. Furthermore, Recharts does not appear to support a method to split the data into multiple tiny areas that can be individually colored, which would enable programming this functionality by splitting the dataset.

Looking into other visualization libraries, several of them seem to lack support for this sort of functionality.

---

### Alternative Libraries

Most libraries do not appear to be able to dynamically split and set a specific fill color. If the library supports multiple series of data, this can be accomplished by breaking the original dataset into partitions with the same color. To implement this, first sort the data and then split the data points into separate data series based off of their derived/computed fill values

For future readers, the reason I suggest an alternative library is that the author of this post states the following in a bounty:

> I am ready to change the library if it has the ability to arbitrarily paint areas

#### ApexCharts.js (open source)

[ApexCharts.js](https://apexcharts.com/) allows specifying multiple data series with different fills with a spline area chart visualization. See this demonstration from the documentation:
https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/area-charts/irregular-timeseries/

As a proof of concept, I have drafted up an implementation that partitions the data-set into multiple series based on the derived color: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-example-forked-x6ii8?file=/src/App.js

The data-set is randomly generated each time; here is an preview example:
[image: areachat with multiple fill colors]

#### CanvasJS (free for non-commercial use or studdents)

[CanvasJS](https://canvasjs.com/) also supports a [spline area chart](https://canvasjs.com/react-charts/spline-area-chart/) with support for multiple data series. Sourced from this [forum post](https://canvasjs.com/forums/topic/change-color-of-spline-area-with-different-values/), here is a jsfiddle that shows off this functionality using multiple data series: http://jsfiddle.net/h8mpu65x/.

Note that this library binds to a DOM element, which should be rendered on [`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

Comment: thanks, the schedule works as i want, but it costs money. maybe there are free analogues?

Comment: @A.Burdonskaya To clarify - CanvasJS is [free](https://canvasjs.com/faq/) for non-commercial or academic projects. Does your project meet those requirements? If not, I will look into another alternative.

Comment: @A.Burdonskaya I have updated my answer with a reference to a free, open-source alternative using ApexCharts.js. The fill opacity in this demonstration is lowered, but can be amended to be a solid fill. You will need to use the same data partitioning scheme based on the derived data's fill color.

Comment: sorry, this is a commercial project, i can't use free license... About ApexChart  - this is very close to what I want, but still not that. I attach an image with an example to the question, please have a look at it

Comment: @A.Burdonskaya I am not sure how quite sure how ApexChart.js does _not_ solve this problem. I have updated my answer with an example proof-of-concept of a dynamic fill using ApexChart.js. The functionality looks very similar, if not identical, to your example.

Comment: you saved me! Thank you very much